# Native Back on Codenameone after using Toolbar class

Tags: java, codenameone

When I use the `Toolbar class` to customize my Toolbar for added functionality the native `back command` disappears, is there a way of getting it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean disappear? This is how i use Toolbar API:

```
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
myForm.setToolbar(t);
t.setTitle("My title");
Command back = new Command("back") {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       myForm.showBack();
   }
};
myForm.setBackCommand(back);
t.addCommandToLeftBar(back);
```

This will take care of both Android hardware back button and placing a back command at the top.

Note that you also have to style `BackCommand` UIID or allow it to use default, Just make sure the default color doesn't match the TitleArea color.

Comment: i have implemented that code and in the `actionPerformed` method put in `f.showBack();` but still no native back functionality

Comment: Can you post a block of code, where your form was instantiated and how you get to the current form.

Comment: Unfortunately in implementing your code suggestion adding the `back command` to both the `Toolbar` and the `form` itself, only one works. With both the command isn't added to `Title area`. But if I comment the part that adds it to the form, I get it back in the title area.. i'm looking for a code implementation that will see both work

Comment: this `back.putClientProperty("uiid", "BackCommand");` is required for the back command to appear like a back button on the Toolbar. I could see that you edited my answer to remove that line and you're also `myForm.showBack();` which will show the current for again when you press back.